# Can I compare the value of the position of an arrangement with a blank? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

this is my problem. I am making a small encryptor so first, I have to keep a string in an array of each of the characters, including the blank space, in order to replace each of the original letters with the one that follows, but I must respect the space blank between each word return the new string.
So, when I am in a position of the arrangement that is worth a blank space I compare it to concat that blank space, this ONLY works when I have two words ex.(Hey you) but if I have more than two ex(Hey you wait) the program doesn't give me any results.
Which should be, encrypted: (ifz zpv xbju).

This is part of my code:

```
const mensaje = {
    mensajeLimpio : '', 
    encriptado : '',
    desencriptado : '',
};

//Arreglo para recorrer el abecedario con respecto al string dado
var arregloAbecedario = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','ñ','o',
                        'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']; 

function encriptar(){
    var arregloCaracteres = [];
    var cadena = '';
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    //Quitamos caracteres especiales como (?!#)
    input = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
    //Quitamos acentos 
    input = input.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
    //Se guarda el mensaje limpio, sin caracteres especiales, solo caracteres.
    mensaje.mensajeLimpio = input;
    arregloCaracteres = input.toLowerCase().split("");
    for( var i=0; i<arregloCaracteres.length ;i++){
        var r = 0;
        //Validamos espacios en blanco
        if (arregloCaracteres[i] === " "){
            cadena = cadena + " ";
        }
        else{
            //Validamos posición actual con respecto a la del arreglo del abecedario, recorremos
            while(arregloCaracteres[i]!==arregloAbecedario[r]){
                r++;
            }
            //Hasta que es igual, guardamos la posicion actual y sumamos uno a su posición en el abecedario
            if(arregloCaracteres[i] === 'z'){
                cadena = cadena + arregloAbecedario[0];
            }
            else{
                cadena = cadena + arregloAbecedario[r+1]; 
            }
        }
    }
    mensaje.encriptado = cadena;
    console.log("Mensaje original: "+mensaje.mensajeLimpio);
    console.log("encriptado: "+mensaje.encriptado);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop risks to run forever:

```
        while(arregloCaracteres[i]!==arregloAbecedario[r]){
            r++;
        }
```

For instance, this happens when your input has the plain letter "n", which does not occur in `arregloAbecedario`.

Instead use `indexOf` and add a space to the result if the index is not found:

```
        var r = arregloAbecedario[r].indexOf(arregloCaracteres[i]);
        if (r >= 0) {
            if(arregloCaracteres[i] === 'z'){
                cadena = cadena + arregloAbecedario[0];
            }
            else{
                cadena = cadena + arregloAbecedario[r+1]; 
            }
        } else {
            cadena = cadena + " ";
        }
```

Note that you should not make your code dependent on "z" being the last character in the list. Instead use modulo logic:

```
        var r = arregloAbecedario[r].indexOf(arregloCaracteres[i]);
        if (r >= 0) {
            cadena = cadena + arregloAbecedario[(r+1) % arregloCaracteres.length];
        } else {
            cadena = cadena + " ";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to this

```
for( var i=0; i<arregloCaracteres.length ;i++){
        //Validamos espacios en blanco
        var r=0;



        if (arregloCaracteres[i] === " "){
            cadena = cadena + " ";
        }
        else{
            while(arregloCaracteres[i]!==arregloAbecedario[r]){
             r++;
            }
            if(arregloCaracteres[i] === 'z'){
                cadena = cadena + arregloAbecedario[0];
            }
            else{
                cadena = cadena + arregloAbecedario[r+1]; 
            }
        }
}
```

What you are doing is you are incrementing 'r' without checking ' ', you need to check whether first whether at current index you have ' ', if not then only increment 'r'

Working example

```js
var arregloAbecedario = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','ñ','o',
                        'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']; 
                        
var arregloCaracteres = 'hey you wait';
var cadena = '';

for( var i=0; i<arregloCaracteres.length ;i++){
            //Validamos espacios en blanco
            var r=0;



            if (arregloCaracteres[i] === " "){
                cadena = cadena + " ";
            }
            else{
                while(arregloCaracteres[i]!==arregloAbecedario[r]){
                 r++;
                }
                if(arregloCaracteres[i] === 'z'){
                    cadena = cadena + arregloAbecedario[0];
                }
                else{
                    cadena = cadena + arregloAbecedario[r+1]; 
                }
            }
    }
    
    console.log(cadena)
```

Comment: Just a code block without explanation of what was causing the problem, and what you changed to resolve it, is not helpful.